# How to check the height of the ui component inside the item when scrolling in the Android Compose Lazy Column

Tags: lazycolumn, android-compose

I was wondering if there is a way to know the internal ui component height of a specific item that is visible in the scroll area when scrolling in the android compose LazyColumn.

In the following way, you can know the height of a specific item displayed in the scroll area, but it is difficult to know the height of the ui component inside the item.

If you have any concerns or resolution on this part, please advise.

If you have a solution, please let me know the sample code and it will be of great help to me.

```
@Composable
internal fun LazyListState.OnVisibleItemsOnScrolled(
    key: String? = null,
    targetVisiblePercent: Int,
    onMostVisibleItem: (mostVisibleRatioItem: VisibleRatioItem?) -> Unit
) {
    val visibleItemsInfo: State<List<LazyListItemInfo>> = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo

        }
    }
}
```